# Flutter Windows - How to open webpage inside the app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, windows, hybrid-mobile-app

I have an enterprise Flutter app which was developed primarily for Android & iOS. We added support for Windows. Currently, the app does the authentication using webview. Below is the current code.

```
openBrowserOverlay(String url) {
  if(Platform.isWindows) {
    launchUrl(Uri.parse(url), mode: LaunchMode.inAppWebView);
  } else {
    FlutterWebBrowser.openWebPage(
      url: url,
      customTabsOptions: CustomTabsOptions(
        instantAppsEnabled: true,
        showTitle: true,
        urlBarHidingEnabled: true,
      ),
      safariVCOptions: SafariViewControllerOptions(
        barCollapsingEnabled: true,
        entersReaderIfAvailable: true,
        modalPresentationCapturesStatusBarAppearance: true,
        dismissButtonStyle: SafariViewControllerDismissButtonStyle.done,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The `flutter_inappwebview` package currently support Android & iOS. For Windows, we used the `url_launcher` package, but it opens the webpage in a new window.

How can:

1. One open webpage inside the windows app?
2. Hide the URL Bar when the web page is opened?

Ideally, a package that works across platform would be best but if its not possible, happy to do condition platform specific coding.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using webview_windows package, it only works on Windows

Answer (score -2):

Use this Flutter plugin:

> https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/webview_flutter

And The Below Code:

```
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('WebView example'),
      ),
      body: const WebView(
        initialUrl: 'SOME URL',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Its not supported on Windows!

Comment: You can use webview_windows 0.3.0 version for Windows App to Launch 
URL https://pub.dev/packages/webview_windows